# Eclipse project keeps freezing

Tags: java, eclipse

Since yesterday my Eclipse keeps freezing when ever I copy/paste text, the content assist window opens, save a class, or undo/redo edits. It's only happening on one of my projects. Here's the only error I can see in my log file:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.ui 2 0 2014-06-20 20:14:50.462
!MESSAGE The 'org.eclipse.jdt.ui.TemplateProposalComputer' proposal computer from the 'org.eclipse.jdt.ui' plug-in did not complete normally. The extension took too long to return from the 'computeCompletionProposals()' operation.
```

Computer specs:
CPU: i7-3930k
GPU: Dual GTX 680's
RAM: 16GB

Eclipse parameters:
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m

Answer (score 0):

I guess you updated the eclipse recently, it might be related to the update process.
please have a look

Bug : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385665